# scss How do I make my mixin takes 3 variables and they all take font-size ranging from 8 to 60?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

The result I want is that when I create a div with classname like
`font-14px-18px-22px-bold`

The font size of the div is 22px, and 18px when tablet, 14px when mobile, and 700 as font weight

the code:

```
$font-weights: (
  'medium': 500,
  'semibold': 600,
  'bold': 700,
);

@mixin typography(
  $font-size,
  $font-size-mobile,
  $font-size-tablet,
  $font-weight
) {
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: map.get($font-weights, $font-weight);

  @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    font-size: $font-size-mobile;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 577px) and (max-width: 992px) {
    font-size: $font-size-tablet;
  }
}
```

and

```
@for $font-size from 8px through 60px {
  @each $font-weight, $font-weight-size in $font-weights {
    .font-#{$font-size}-#{$font-weight} {
      @include typography($font-size, $font-weight);
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried something like

```
@for $font-size-mobile from 8px through 60px {
  @for $font-size-tablet from 8px through 60px {
    @for $font-size from 8px through 60px {
      @each $font-weight, $font-weight-size in $font-weights {
        .font-#{$font-size-mobile}-#{$font-size-tablet}-#{$font-size}-#{$font-weight} {
          @include typography(
            $font-size-mobile,
            $font-size-tablet,
            $font-size,
            $font-weight
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It does not work cause triple nested loop is just too much

Edit: To clarify my question:
let's say I used to have a piece of code like this:

```
@mixin typography(
  $font-size,
  $font-weight
) {
  font-size: $font-size;
  font-weight: map.get($font-weights, $font-weight);
}
```

and as well as second piece of code in the question.

so when I typed `font-18px-bold`, I get a text with 18px size and bold weight.
Now I need to modify the code so I can type `font-12px-14px-18px-bold` for mobile and tablet

Comment: In the first "@for" loop, you are required to pass four arguments to `typography` but you are passing only two. You haven't specified whether the other two arguments are optional or not?

Comment: @deepanshu the first for loop means the code before considering mobile and tablet, for the current code, please refer to the third piece of code

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirement. Can you post expected output? If you want your mixin to take three variables, why not make one optional or remove it?

Comment: So what I understood is that you want to generate all possible combinations from 8 to 60, for desktop, mobile and tablet. Is that what you want? Do you really want to generate that much amount (half a million)? I am not an expert but I think that might not be practical?

Comment: @deepanshu it is not a must, I have already found a workaround for this. Though I am still curious if it is possible